# terminals aren't opening in restart script

Tags: python, linux, timer, barcode, application-restart

My overall objective is to have a program that takes in barcode scans and if after a given period of time there is no barcode scan then kill the programs and restart it. right now I'm trying to get the program to restart after a given period of time, but instead of rebooting, it just kills the program and never boots it up.

I'm guessing the issue is between the **barcoderestart.sh** script and the **starttimer.py** script as thus far everything else works as expected.

I have included all the code in case there is anything else concerning

I have a restart script that kills the terminals and reruns the programs:
**barcoderestart.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
     
pkill -f lxterminal 
sleep 1 
pkill -f lxterminal 
sync 
sleep 5 
export DISPLAY=:0.0
    
lxterminal -e /home/nvidia/local_orch/utilities/barcodetest.sh & 
sleep 5
```

It then runs **barcodetest.sh** script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/nvidia/local_orch/utilities

python3 ./barcodetest.py
```

**barcodetest.py** script:

```
def writeLog(l):
    lt = time.localtime(time.time())
    global insstarttime
    insstarttime = lt
    lt2 = str(lt[0])+"-"+str(lt[1])+"-"+str(lt[2])+"-"+str(lt[3])+"."+str(lt[4])+"."+str(lt[5])
    lg = lt2+" : "+l
    with open('barcodetest.txt','a') as lfile:
        lfile.write(lg+"\n")
        print(lg)
    return 0
    
    while not stopped:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
      
    print('Fire in the hole!!')

while True:
    lt = time.localtime(time.time())
    rawscan = ''
    while sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],0)[0]:
        input0 = sys.stdin.readline()
        if input0:
            rawscan = input0.rstrip()
            PN = rawscan[0:7]
            serial = rawscan[8:]
            serial = serial.strip()


            print("Part number is "+PN)
            print("serial is "+ serial)
            writeLog("RAW Scan is "+rawscan)
            os.system("lxterminal -e /home/nvidia/local_orch/utilities/timer.sh")
```

As soon as I scan part it starts the **timer.sh** script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/nvidia/local_orch/utilities

python3 ./starttimer.py
```

It  starts the **startimer.py** and after a given time it should restart the program.

```
def countdown(t):
 while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
      
    print('Fire in the hole!!')
countdown(int(5))
time.sleep(1)
os.system("/home/nvidia/local_orch/utilities/barcoderestart.sh")
```

however when it reaches the end of the time, it just kills the programs and never reboots

**barcodetest.sh** script. It isn't giving me any error codes.

Comment: Wild guess: you happen to be in an `lxterminal` when you invoke the script? It then shoots itself and never makes it to the first sleep?

Comment: So if I run barcoderestart.sh script while it's waiting for a barcode scan, it reboots just fine. I guess I could write a script that checks every minute if it's running and if it isn't, run the restart script?

Comment: I would just use `pkill -f barcodetest.sh` ...

Comment: you don't need a whole script for running a process with a timeout. Check out the documentation for the `timeout` utility. Furthermore, the whole program is needlessly convoluted, what you have here is a `python` script calling a `bash` script which then calls a `python` script, the architecture you are following could easily create many zombie-child processes that you've no method of handlig

Comment: I ended up writing a script within the loop that didn't have a visible counter rather than going down this route. I couldn't figure it out that way and this other way seems to work. Thanks for your help